# Running both Springboot and Rest endpoints in one project/application Java

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I'm getting very confused over whether you can or can't run spring boot stuff and REST endpoints in one application. At the moment I have them in separate project directories, running the springboot UI one with:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LeagueProjectUiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LeagueProjectUiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and the REST rest endpoints with:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

and my jersey and tomcat stuff are declared in my pom.xml

Rest:

```
@Path("/university")
public class University {

@GET
@Path("/{universitycode}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response returnSingleSummoner(
        @PathParam("universitycode") String universityCode) {

}
```

What's the best way of running both SpringBoot and REST endpoints at the same time, or am I getting completely confused!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say REST endpoints, do you mean Jersey endpoints?

`Spring Boot` supports Jersey,as you can see, for example,  [here,](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/01/getting-started-with-jersey-and-spring-boot.html)  so nothing theoretically should stop you for putting everything in one application as long as request paths are different.

Comment: After a bit of work I managed to consolidate them! I was over-complicating things a lot, and now it's working great, thank you :) And yes, I did.